# Midrash Rabbah - User Friendly Edition

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, midrash

Can someone recommend a user friendly edition of Midrash Rabbah? To be more specific, I am looking for an edition that has - a) clear print b) user friendly layout that is good for study b) explanations and commentary c) an all-Hebrew text, and d) an accurate, well edited text

I asked a similar question previously, but that was about finding a critical edition of Midrash Rabbah. I am asking a different question here.

Comment: I dont want to hijack your post, but neither do I want to post such a similar question separately, so just tell me if you would like me to delete this comment and I will. But I have been having awful eye strain lately, and was wondering if there is Midrash Rabbah audio format, or any midrash that are regularly studied, or even something new, that is available in audio so I can still learn but give my eyes a rest. If someone knows and can respond in the comments without hijacking your answers, great. If it's a distraction here, I will delete this no problem,and dont feel bad to say so if it is!

Answer (score 1):

[Artscroll](https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/mrb.html) have a beautiful set that ticks all of your requirements.

It comes in three sizes and has very clear print with the full page of commentaries. See a sample page below:

[image]

It also has the added bonus of having translation if that is something that you are after.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. How do you think it compares to the Moznaim and Oz VeHadar editions of Midrash Rabbah? https://ozvehadar.us/midrash-rabbah-hameshulav-with-commentary/ and https://moznaim.com/products/medresh-rabbah-%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94?_pos=7&_sid=703625c34&_ss=r

Comment: They're all good! Well for a start it is probably a lot more expensive! You need to decide if you need the aid of English translation or not?

Comment: I don't need the English, but I'll probably need something like the Biur of the Oz VeHadar edition. Do you happen to know how the accuracy of the Oz VeHadar edition compares to the others? I've noticed the that the texts of midrashim can vary quite a bit.

Comment: Artscroll (Hebrew page) and Moznaim (Wagshal) are very similar and have only the full texts of the traditional commentaries (as per the Vilna edition). Artscroll brings the explanations and insights in the English part. Oz Vehadar and Machon HaMidrash Ha'mevoar do more of a line by line commentary and insights, similar to the English Artscroll. Oz Vehadar seems to cover more ground.

Comment: What do you mean by 'covers more ground?'

Comment: I mean it seems to me that Oz Vehadar gives you more information. Compare the examples here: Machon: https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6571728/original/75ca47df0ef2981191b704da514b6593.jpg Oz Vehadar: http://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=76681&sid=4a1d605a8efc958980696e905ec6867a